# Passing boost::function that takes a template argument as a parameter defaulted to NULL

Tags: c++, templates, boost, functor

I am trying to make a function like this:

```
template<typename T, typename Val>
void someFun(vector<T>& container, int a, int b, int c, boost::function<bool(T&)> selector = NULL)
{
    Val* ptrToElement = someGetElementFunction(container[i]);
    if (selector && selector(*ptrToElement))
    {
      cout << "do something!" << endl;
    }
}
```

so that selector is optional and can be either passed or not, the usage should be as appears below:

```
someFun(1,2,3);
boost::function<int(someClass&)> someSelector = boost::bind(...)
someFun(1,2,3, someSelector);
```

but it appears that it cannot be done due to the type T being generic, can this be bypassed anyway or perhaps there is a better solution to this problem?

---

edit:
Sorry it appears that I havent given enough details, the function is actually an element selector, the whole example is now edited and should look clearer.

So until now it has been handled by always passing some function even if there was no selector needed and all the elements were supposed to be processed by the function, it was handled by passing:

```
boost::function<bool(someObject&)> selectAllObjects = boost::lambda::constant(true);
someFun(someObjContainer, 1, 2, 3, selectAllObjects);
```

but this solution looks terrible by desgin, whenever all objects are to be selected, you have to make that stupid selectAll selector and pass it further. I was trying to eliminate it by passing an optional function and process selecting elements only when the pointer is not NULL.

The problem with overloading is a lot of duplicated code, assume that someFun consists of 20 lines of code, overloading it just to add that functionality would double it.

---

Edit 2:
I found the solution, if someone would have a similar problem then theres explaination:

Thank you guys for the help, sorry for not making myself clear in the beginning, it probably would have saved me lots of time:(. But anyway - the problem was a little bit more sophisticated, the container wasn't just a mere value container but a container of keys to a dictionary from which the values could be obtained, therefore the type T is actually the type of keys. The compiler couldn't infer the Val type because it simply wasn't explicitly passed when calling the function (which seems pretty obvious now...).

The following obviously works:

```
someFun<int, myClass>(someVector, 1, 2, 3);
someFun<int, myClass>(someVector, 1, 2, 3, someSelector);
```

There is even no need to overload anything :), thanks.

Comment: Don't use `NULL`, use [`nullptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr).

Comment: Overloading doesn't mean duplicating all the code, they can share a common implementation, or one can call the other

Answer (score 1):

When you call `someFun(1, 2, 3)` the compiler doesn't know which specialization of the function template you mean, because it can't deduce the what type `T` should be. It can't create a default parameter of type `function<void(T&)>` without knowing what `T` is.

In C++11 you can add a default template argument for `T` if there's a sensible default you can use:

```
template<typename T = int>
void someFun(int a, int b, int c, boost::function<int(T&)> funPtr = nullptr)
{
}
```

But the design of the function doesn't really make sense ... what do you hope to do with the `function` object if you don't know what type it is?

It would probably make more sense to have two overloaded functions:

```
void someFun(int a, int b, int c);

template<typename T>
void someFun(int a, int b, int c, boost::function<int(T&)> funPtr);
```

Comment: One note; the compiler still will not be able to infer `T` based on the signature of the `boost::function` passed to `someFun<T>()`. If you really want that feature, instead of taking `boost::function<int(T&)>`, just take `const T&` and then use some combination of `static_assert`s and `enable_if`s to prevent having it called with invalid types (though you could argue that as long as it compiles, the type must be ok!).

Comment: I added some more details to the first post, sorry not it should look somewhat clearer

Comment: You should have posted the real function from the start, `T` can be deduced from `vector<T>`, and it should compile fine, so I don't know what the problem is

Comment: @Sebbie Can't you just add a three-parameter overload that delegates to the four-parameter one with `boost::lambda::constant(true)` as parameter 4 (or a null function if you prefer null checks to calling a dummy function)?